# Can't get to some web sites

Tags: networking, dns, resolv.conf

I changed my DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf and /systemd/resolved.conf to Google DNS and I cannot access some websites.

Solved: Turns out I have changed my DNS configuration in the past, member heynnema helped me a lot to fix it. Thank you very much for your patience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't manually edit /etc/resolv.conf. It says so right in the file.

Open the Wired Settings panel. Select your desired connection profile. Go to IPv4 tab. Turn OFF DNS Automatic. Enter "8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4" in the DNS field.

[image]

**Update #1:**

Or edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf from the terminal CLI. See `man resolved.conf` for help in formatting the DNS= field.

**Update #2:**

You've changed your DNS configuration. We'll try this and see if it fixes your access to www.linkomanija.net.

Edit /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, and change the DNS= line to only contain THREE servers, not four.

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # delete this manually created file

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the symlink

Retry your web site.

`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved` # you MAY have to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107694/discussion-between-heynnema-and-shiusho).

Comment: it worked!!! thank you very much for your patience and hard work!

Comment: @shiu'sho You're very welcome!

Comment: I bought a new laptop, installed ubuntu, changed /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to:

`DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

but my DNS remained of ISP's. Where is the issue here?

Comment: @shiu'sho New computer, new problem... please start a new question. Thanks.

Comment: did that. Please take a look:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279298/how-do-i-change-my-dns-on-the-terminal/1279318#1279318