# How do I change my DNS on the terminal?

Tags: dns

EDITED:

I modified my netplan settings but it still does not work.

Ubuntu 20.04

`cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`  :

```
   # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    ethernets:
       wlp2s0:
          dhcp4: false
          addresses: [192.168.1.128/24]
          gateway4: 192.168.1.254
          nameservers:
             addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
```

Comment: How do you know that your system isn't using the DNS server you've specified?  Are you using firefox? Firefox is starting to push DoH which won't use the DNS servers defined on your system or even from your network or your ISP.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? What does the `terminal` have to do with changing DNS? Report back.

Comment: @heynnema

Ubuntu desktop. 

I want to learn cli, so I try to do everything on terminal :)

Comment: See `nmtui` and `nm-connection-editor` and `nmcli`. The /etc/netplan/*.yaml file should be reverted to just the first 4 lines.

Comment: @heynnema I checked them and the settings are there (I mean those I made in the yaml file are in nmtui and nm-connection-editor). BUT, I think it does not work because it has been set for an ethernet connection and not WiFi. Can it be the case?

Comment: No, you've set the .yaml file to use wlp2s0 which is your wireless, but it's incomplete, and should be edited as I suggest. I'd recommend abandoning the CLI-learning experiment for now, and get this running via GUI... then come back and play with CLI on a working system. Edit your .yaml. Edit the `Wired Connection` (assuming you want an ethernet connection, otherwise edit your wireless connection profile) settings via the NM GUI.

Comment: nmtui and nm-connection-editor are fine - DNS settings are there. What exactly should be done in nmcli?

Answer (score 2):

First find your connection name you want to change and note the name of it:

```
nmcli connection
```

Then use nmcli to change the DNS settings:

```
nmcli connection modify <interface name> ipv4.dns "<DNS Server>,<DNS Server>"
```

Check your interface to ensure that it has been updated correctly:

```
nmcli connection show <interface name>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. From the terminal, open up `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`, I prefer to use nano: `# nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`. (The file may be named differently, if `01-network-manager-all.yaml` doesn't exist use `ls /etc/netplan` to see what the filename is.)
2. Find the part that has `nameservers` and addresses:

```yaml
nameservers:
    addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

3. You can add any number of nameservers there, just separate them with commas.
4. When you're done making changes, save the file and run `# netplan apply`.
5. (Optional) To confirm that your changes were made, run `$ systemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2`. The nameservers you selected should be displayed.

Comment: output from `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` :

`# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager`

there is no nameservers there

Comment: Then make the change in Network Manager. Since you want to use the terminal, that means using `nmcli`. See `man nmcli`.

Comment: updated my question, please take a look

Comment: Hmm, once you're done editing the file run `# netplan apply` and `# sudo restart network-manager`, see if that fixes things. If not, what's the output of `ystemd-resolve --status | grep 'DNS Servers' -A2`?

Comment: output: `DNS Servers: 192.168.1.254
          DNS Domain: ~.           
                      lan    `

Comment: any help here??

Comment: I still have not fixed, can anyone help please?

Comment: @shiu'sho try the other answer above